# MYSQL database error out in Azure timer trigger function after deployed from VS code even it works fine on local

Tags: mysql, azure, connection-string

I created an Azure timer trigger function using MYSQL database connector by C# in visual studio code.  it tested good on my development PC but errored out after successful deployment on Azure.

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Result: Failure Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.GetTaskForValueTaskSource(IValueTaskSource t) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.CompleteConnectAsync(Task task) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.<>c.b__38_0(Exception ex) at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at

It did not help after I added connector sting under configuration. [https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-database-connection/#:~:text=1%20Log%20in%20to%20the%20Azure%20Portal%202,Connection%20String%20to%20add%20the%20database%20connection%20string](https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-database-connection/#:%7E:text=1%20Log%20in%20to%20the%20Azure%20Portal%202,Connection%20String%20to%20add%20the%20database%20connection%20string).
I am not sure if my connector string is correct format, or I missed something in configuration.

SERVER=<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com; user id=; password=; database=boppwh

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Ash.Function
{
    public class AshDaily
    {
        readonly MySqlConnection bp1db = new("SERVER=<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com; user id=.user name>; password=<password>; database=boppwh");
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public AshDaily(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AshDaily>();
        }

        [Function("AshDaily")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            bp1db.Open();
            string query1 = "SELECT COUNT(cellid) AS free1 FROM cells WHERE Status = 0";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new(query1, bp1db);
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            string freecell = String.Empty;
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                freecell = reader1.GetString("free1");
            }
            reader1.Close();
            bp1db.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(freecell);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you run the code without the worker and check if there also comes an error, the inner error note would show you the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to **`SslMode=Preferred;`** not being present in your connection string. I tried adding it to my code below and it worked successfully both locally and after deploying it to Azure, as you can see in the output below. Check that your firewall permits connections to the **MySql** Server.

Below is the code I tried which provides output both locally and in the Azure Portal:

```cs
public static class MySqlFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MySqlTimerFunction")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        string server = "azserv6391.mysql.database.azure.com";
        string database = "boppwh";
        string username = "azsql6391";
        string password = "*****";
        int port = 3306;

        string connectionString = $"Server={server};Port={port};Database={database};User ID={username};Password={password};SslMode=Preferred;";

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                string query = "SELECT * FROM cells;";

                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                log.LogInformation($"Cell ID: {reader["cellid"]}, Status: {reader["status"]}");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            log.LogInformation("No rows found.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

On the local machine:

[image]

In Azure:

[image]

As @nbk suggested in the comment, you can also run the code without a `worker` to solve this. I tried it in the above code and it ran successfully.